# How to download from command line a file that is generated by server side PHP software

Tags: php, command-line, cron, download, forms, http-post

The reason for this is to be able to schedule a task that will download a CSV file generated from a form every day without human action.

So far, I have been able to generate an HTML file that trigger a POST on a form that calls the reporting PHP file.

Here is a short version of the HTML generated

```
<form name="reporttocsv" method="post" action="/RequestForm.php">
<input type="hidden" name="day" value="29">
<input type="hidden" name="month" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="year" value="2018">
<input type="hidden" name="span" value="30">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="csv">
<input type="IMAGE" name="csv" value="csv" src="export.png">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">document.reporttocsv.submit();</script>
```

Opening this .html in a browser automatically call the RequestForm.php and trigger the download of a .csv file.  So I dont have to click on the picture anymore.

Now I would like download the csv from command line without using a browser.
I tried to play with wget and curl, but in both case, it saved the html file, not the resulting csv.  Maybe I used the wrong tools, or misused them.

Any idea/suggestion on how to do such a thing would be appreciated.

I do my best, but english is not my primary language.  Ask if you dont understand.

Thanks a lot, really appreciated

Comment: Your browser contains a Javascript interpreter and this submits your form and downloads RequestForm.php. On the command line you don't have a javascript interpreter.

Comment: Thanks.  So, I have to start from the begining again.  Anyway to POST data to a form from command line?

Comment: Not directly from the command line, but there is this: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Thanks @KIKO, if I understand correctly using this will not let the called PHP see values as a POST, but just as parameters and I can't modify the PHP being called.  I found something that might help me, but again, I am worried that, like for lack of javascript in command line, I missed something.  It's the command **curl --data**.  I will look into it.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to emulate a POST with *curl*, see: https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post You could write a PHP script that translates command line arguments to POST variables. But perhaps you can do that on the command line with '--data'?